# Add product tab above more info

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How do i add a customized product tab above More Info for the product page in prestashop? For now I am hard coding that part but it takes alot of time especially if more products will be adding the same feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register two hooks (or more) in your module:

```
public function hookProductTabContent($args)
public function hookProductTab($args)
```

Use these two functions to add tab markup (tab markup are different in PS1.5 and PS1.6)

If you want to able to edit a tab (or tabs) for each product, use these hooks:

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra()
public function hookActionProductSave()
```

If you need more than one custom tab foreach product, you will have to use some kind of list in the hook above and that will be complicated.